# 'Messenger class does not exist in this context' - MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm trying to use the MVVM Light `Messenger` class and have created a ViewModel class using the template. When trying to use the method `Messenger.Default.Register` however, the `Messenger` class does not seem to be defined. Am I missing a reference or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Messenger class is included in GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll. Make sure in your References folder that the reference has been added, and is not broken.

Cheers,
Laurent

Comment: Thanks! I added the Galasoft.MvvmLight.WPF4.dll instead of this

Answer (score 0):

A similar error message could also be triggered if attempting to register outside a method or a constructor.

[image]